# Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good morning friends, sorry for the inconvenience I am doing practices to learn and I was doing a login, but the problem is that I am trying to connect it to an api and it does not make the connection, it gives me a super strange error in the login component
Here I attach the login.component

```
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';
import { AppserviceService } from '../../services/appservice.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppsResp } from '../../interfaces/interfaces';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {

  email:string ='';
  password:string='';

  constructor(public AppserviceService: AppserviceService) { }

  login() {
    const user = {email: this.email, password: this.password};
    this.AppserviceService.login(user).subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

the error that fits is the following_  "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
appservice.service.ts(15, 26): An argument for 'password' was not provided."

Here I attach the app services service, which is where the origin of the error marks me

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Query } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppsResp, Registro } from '../interfaces/interfaces';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppserviceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



  login ( email: string, password: string ){
const body = {email,password}
return this.http.post <AppsResp>("http://apitest.e-bango.com/api/auth/login" , body );
  }

  }
```

Likewise, I can't find the correct logic to insert the registry component in my service, can you help me? and explain in as much detail as possible what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Looking at the signature `login ( email: string, password: string )`, it should be called like `this.AppserviceService.login(user.email, user.password)`. 
The way you originally tried it, is like, when `login( arg1, arg2 )` expects two arguments, you have `arg1 = {user: "user1@some.domain", password: "password1"}` and `arg2 not provided`, which does not work. Rather, it should be `arg1 = "user1@some.domain"` and `arg2 = "password1"`. To get those strings from the `user` object, use user.email and user.password respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 ways to resolve this problem

1: Your input to function login is not correct

```
 login() {
    const user = {email: this.email, password: this.password};
    this.AppserviceService.login(user).subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Change to

```
 login() {
    this.AppserviceService.login(email: this.email, password: this.password).subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

2: Change the function login

```
  login ( email: string, password: string ){
const body = {email,password}
return this.http.post <AppsResp>("http://apitest.e-bango.com/api/auth/login" , body );
  }
```

to

```
  login ( {email: string, password: string }){
const body = {email,password}
return this.http.post <AppsResp>("http://apitest.e-bango.com/api/auth/login" , body );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change login method in appserviceService

```js
login ( body ){
  return this.http.post <AppsResp>("http://apitest.e-bango.com/api/auth/login" , body );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

its because your .login from AppserviceService is accepts or excepts 2 arguments, this is email and password. But you gonna put there user object

try this

```
export class LoginComponent {
  email:string ='';
  password:string='';

  constructor(public AppserviceService: AppserviceService) { }

  login() {
    this.AppserviceService.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#function-declarations) in the docs

```
login ({email, password}){
  ...
}
```

You can also give values by defect

```
login ({email="",password=""}){
  ...
}
```

And you can indicate the type

```
login(({email="",password=""}:{email?:string,password?:string}){
  ...
}
```

If you use "optional parameters" use `?` to indicate is optional

BTW: you can pass the user itself

```
login(user:{email?:string,password?:string}){
  return this.http.post(...,user);
}
```